# Incorrect information in C# tag info?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

My question is about the `c#` info page, here on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info

To be precise, my question is about this sentence

> C# 8.0 will introduce nullable reference types which enables reference types (e.g. string) to be null,

I believe the wording seems off, for me it reads like prior to `c# 8` a reference type couldn't be null and `c# 8` will introduce the ability to store a null in a reference type, eg. that this would be impossible in `c#` prior to version 8:

```
string foo = null;
```

And only with `c# 8` its possible to declare a `nullable reference type` by doing this:

```
string? foo = null;
```

Which, I believe, is wrong - `c#` always made it possible that a reference type could be null.

There was no explicit way to distinguish a `nullable` from a `non-nullable` reference type and every reference type was in fact a `nullable`.

My attempt to summarize the feature in one small sentence would be:

> C# 8.0 will introduce an explicit way to define nullable reference types (eg. string? (nullable), string (non-nullable)), ...

Comment: Generally, the [C# chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) probably is the right place to discuss the C# tag info. If you already have a proposal for how to adjust it, you can also just go ahead and edit (after the currently pending edit is reviewed, that is).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - didn't know I could edit the info tag - I will give this question, some time before trying my luck in the chat - thx for that info

Comment: The tag wiki seems like a really poor place to try to describe possible features of unreleased versions of a language.  Honestly I don't see the tag wiki to be a place to just list out every feature in every version of a language, but at a *minimum* you'd want to keep it to versions of the language that are actually released.

Comment: The name of the feature is correct, the source calls them *nullable reference types*. It's the description that's incorrect.

Comment: @Stijn - totally agree with you thats why my "proposal" still contains the name tries a different take in the describing part

Comment: My bad, seems like I misread your proposed change. Looks good.

Comment: I altered it. Pray, if needs be, alter it further.

Comment: Yes, the name is official (but also misleading). The novelty are never-null reference variables. But altogether better to remove this from the tag description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I follow c# rather closely, but since it is holiday time haven't read every nuance. This one seems to be interesting, although it does introduce technical debt unfortunately.

> Any variable where the ? is not appended to the type name is a non-nullable reference type. That includes all reference type variables in existing code when you have enabled this feature.
>
> - The variable must be initialized to a non-null value.
> - The variable can never be assigned the value null.

This is a rather interesting caveat indeed, since I am sure many older codebases have initialized a reference type to null in order to use it later. Not to mention the **default** keyword. That said, there is a lot of nuance involved in these types of situations and it is probably best to simply leave this amount of nuance to the actual MSDN posts on them #RTFM (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Tag wikis in general suffer from neglect in development. They have never really changed, and are a sort of barely organized chaos. Still, they should at the very least be accurate. What they don't need, as stated above, is such granularity.

I would suggest simply taking note of the overall improvements of C# 8, as the other versions do, and leave it there for others to investigate on their own if interested.

> C# 8.0, [currently in preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/), will introduce nullable reference types, ranges and indices, and asynchronous streams.

Let's not get too verbose in the tag wikis, they are already massive and relatively unorganized (mostly due to a lack of available features for organization). There is a strength in brevity.

Comment: The language still remains terrible. In say, C# 4, MyObject is still a reference type (as opposed to being a value type, i.e. a struct), and it could still be set to nil then. What it should be called is a "annotation", i.e. a "nullable annotation for reference type". Apple uses this language for the Swift language, which have "optionals" (essentially what C# is adding in 8.0)

Comment: "This is a rather interesting caveat indeed, since I am sure many older codebases have initialized a reference type to null in order to use it later...." AFAIK this is an opt-in behavior, it won't change automatically

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I don't see how that comment is relevant. How is c# 4 relevant to a c# 8 question? How is an Apple language relevant? That comment is just unwanted rant

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - That is correct. Either in the project settings file (.csproj) or by use of a nullable context. My point was using it would introduce some level of technical debt in order to convert.

Answer (score 3):

Just for readability I'd use backticks ` around types. Especially now that the question mark `?` will be used profusely it is important to see that it's not part of the sentence.

Compare this:

> C# 8.0 will introduce an explicit way to define nullable reference types (eg. string? (nullable), string (non-nullable)), ...

To this:

> C# 8.0 will introduce an explicit way to define nullable reference types (eg. `string?` (nullable), `string` (non-nullable)), ...